# Do we get the same punishment for supporting the murderer?

Tags: fiqh, punishment, non-muslim-countries

I basically bought a bottle of Sprite, because of I didn't know what the other options are (e.g. Tastes). Coca Cola supports Israel, as you know. When buying it, I felt like I'm supporting the evil, yet I still continued buying it. Even if with or without that intention, am I still counted as a murderer?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question specifically my brother. However, it discusses why we as muslims have to boycott israel supporting products http://www.inminds.com/boycott-fatwas.html#qar , feel free to check it.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel It really doesn't. What I want to know is that am I still counted as a murderer, just because what I mentioned above?

Comment: Oops @Hudaverdi, I strongly approve and appreciate your fantastic question. Unfortunately many of Muslims don't notice how much they are supporting them by buying those product. And as dear Muslim mentioned (based on the narrations...) they'll be partner in ... by buying and finally supporting them indirectly. God really bless you for discussing such significant question. / Actually I assume that a major aspect of their financial source can be related to selling these product. I myself endeavor never drink them ... Gooood luck mate.

Answer (score 2):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarakatuhu,

Relating to your title question I went ahead and researched on it:-

INVOLVING IN MURDER

Volume 9, Book 83, Number 3: 
Narrated 'Abdullah bin 'Umar:
One of the evil deeds with bad consequence from which there is no escape for the one who is involved in it is to kill someone unlawfully.

Volume 9, Book 83, Number 6: 
Narrated 'Abdullah:
The Prophet said, "No human being is killed unjustly, but a part of responsibility for the crime is laid on the first son of Adam who invented the tradition of killing (murdering) on the earth. (It is said that he was Qabil).

Imam Ja’far as-Sadiq (RA) says,
“The Holy Prophet (S) was told that a Muslim has been killed and his corpse is lying on the street. When the Holy Prophet (S) and his companions reached the site of the murder, he enquired as to who the killer was.”
The people said, “We do not know.” The Prophet was surprised,
“A person has been killed among the Muslims, and no one knows of his killer?”
“By the Almighty who appointed me with Prophethood, If all the creatures of the heavens and the earth participate in the murder of a Muslim and be pleased upon that, then Allah would surely involve them in punishment and send them all to Hell.”
The lesson derived from this hadith is that there is no difference between the killer and those who support or co-operate with him.
Imam Muhammad al-Baqir (a.s.) has said,
“On the day of Qiyāma a person would be presented before Allah. He will be having a streak of blood (like one gets a cut while shaving). He will say,
‘By Allah, I have not killed anyone. Not have I co-operated with anyone’s murder.’ Allah will say, ‘Yes, but one day you spoke about a believer and your words caused him to be killed. Hence you are responsible for his murder.’”
Hazrat Imam Riďa (a.s.) said,
“If someone is killed in the east and one who lives in the west is pleased upon this, then he is a partner in this murder."

But regarding your elaborated statement, boycotting is something we people are doing to not support Israels on developing or selling their products which includes Mc donalds, pepsi, lays etc. but I am not so good on this topic. :)

Comment: Am I still counted as a murderer? I'm very scared.

Comment: You are buying the products which has no connections to them killing many innocent, it is not as though you are supporting them to buy the military facilities etc. This is my thought: that unless they utilize the money in to buying more weapons or military resources, just my thought. Conclusion is that you are innocent and not at all involved in such sin.

Comment: I felt like I was supporting them,  and bought it anyways.

Comment: Dear Muslim and Hudaverdi, I assume we can be considered in their negative act indirectly by supporting or actually buying their products (indirectly) / In the meantime, @Muslim, bravo for presenting such nice hadiths as helpful traditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title and body is confusing. The title makes it look you are part of the actual murder (action wise).

In Islam there is no such as boycotting, even from your enemies during war time.

> The Muslims are unanimously agreed that it is permissible to interact with ahl al-dhimmah (non-Muslims living under Muslim rule) and other kuffaar, so long as the object of the transaction is not haraam, but it is not permissible for a Muslim to sell weapons or tools of war to those who are waging war against the Muslims, or anything that helps them to support their religion.

Source: http://islamqa.info/en/20732

Feel free to buy from any company you want regardless of their political or religious standpoint, whom they support or what they believe in

Comment: I felt like I was supporting them when buying it.

Comment: I felt like I was supporting them for the massacre.

Comment: What about selling phones and computers produced by me in their country?

Comment: @HüdaverdiAlperenDemirok My answer goes both ways, selling and buying.